# Encryption of a number sequence in java

Tags: java, encryption

We're making a program that involves encrypting a reference number. However, the end result should still be a number, but two digits shorter than the original length of the reference number. Is there any algorithm or method to do this?

Comment: Is the orig number you're encrypting actually in string format?  ex. "255".  If so, convert it to hex (or binary) and it's automatically shorter.

Comment: The end result of encryption doesn't have digits at all, let alone two digits less than the source. It is just binary data. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

In general the size of the encrypted output is either larger or equal, and it will only be the same length for specific cases (equal or less than block size with a specific algorithm, or when a unique number is present to act as IV).

Of course, you could perform some kind of compression before encrypting, if that is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

It may come as a supprise bud encryption is not the only option if you need something to keep something secret. Encryption should be used carefully and with caution, beacuse you might just be substituting one problem for the next (for i.e. key management problem).

Not everywhere but, sometimes there is a possibility of a different solution. If you wan't let's say to issue a number by which you can retrive associated data, you could add another column in table for a random number, and issue this number, instead of ancrypted ID or other encrypted value. And you also could freely limit the size of resulting number.